# MySql - Conditional setting

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

Resolved: Basic error, no commas separating the list of SET values

I am trying to include a conditional statement in a UPDATE/SET in MySql. I have tried three different attempts (all hashed out). What am I doing wrong?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare(
            "UPDATE mytable1 tb1, mytable2 tb2 "
            . "SET "
            . "tb1.Value1 = (tb1.Value1 + :Value1Diff) "
            //. "IF tb1.Slot >= 0 THEN tb2.ValueBitwise=(tb2.ValueBitwise | (1 << tb1.Slot)); END IF; "
            //. "tb2.ValueBitwise= CASE WHEN tb1.Slot >= 0 THEN (tb2.ValueBitwise | (1 << tb1.Slot)) ELSE tb2.ValueBitwise END "
            . "tb2.ValueBitwise=IF(tb1.Slot >= 0, tb2.ValueBitwise | (1 << tb1.Slot), tb2.ValueBitwise) "
            . "tb1.Value2 = :Value2 "
            . "WHERE "
            . "tb1.Property1=tb2.Property2");
$stmt->execute(array(':Value1Diff' => $Value1Diff, ':Value2 ' => $Value2));
```

Comment: Can you describe the exact problem you're having?

Comment: It tells me there is an error in my sql around the line "tb2.ValueBitwise=IF(tb1.Slot >= 0, tb2.ValueBitwise | (1 << tb1.Slot), tb2.ValueBitwise) " (or the other two equivalents). Everything else is fine. If I remove that line it works, but does not make the necessary update to tb2.ValueBitwise.

Comment: Missing commas, eg after "tb1.Value1 = (tb1.Value1 + :Value1Diff)". Should be "tb1.Value1 = (tb1.Value1 + :Value1Diff),"